# how to save XML fragment?

Tags: c#, xml, string, var

the code:

```
    var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputz, readerSettings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                using (var fragmentReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    if (fragmentReader.Read())
                    {
                        var fragment = XNode.ReadFrom(fragmentReader) as XElement;
```

what its outputting:

```
    <sys>
      <id>FSB</id>
      <label>FSB</label>
      <value>266</value>
    </sys>
     <sys>
      <id>CPU</id>
      <label>speed</label>
      <value>2930</value>
    </sys>
```

how would i change it so that it writes "value" to a string instead? so the output looks like :  ,266,2930

thanks

Comment: Do you want the entire XML snippet to be converted to a string, or do you want to retrieve some nodes - e.g. the `value`? If you are working with the 'sys' node, it's probably best to keep it as XML until you are displaying / comparing values.

Comment: The code section you have shown does not actually output anything; it just reads the xml and stores it in a variable. You'll have to give us the line which is generating the output...

Comment: i changed first post:) look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the obvious answer is to convert to a string -

```
var stringFragment = fragment.ToString();
```

or, if necessary,

```
var fragment = (XNode.ReadFrom(fragmentReader) as XElement).ToString();
```

I'm not 100% sure this will achieve what you're trying to do, but it will return your XML snippet as a string.

**edit**

Now that the question has been updated, I can give some more information. I'll assume that each `fragment` is in fact the `sys` node.

You first need to get the `value` node, and then retrieve its 'value' (ie its content).

```
var valueNode = fragment.Element("value");
var content = valueNode.Value;
```

Comment: thanks fro the additional info, but snooping around MSDN i found out how to: reader.ReadToFollowing("value");
                                    
                                    port.Write(reader.ReadElementContentAsString() + ","); is this the best way in terms of performance? or it probably doesnt matter that much does it.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess:

```
 var fragment = (XNode.ReadFrom(fragmentReader)).ToString();
```